# how to configure Node Manager In bea WebLogic 8.16?

Tags: weblogic, bea

I am working with BEA weblogic 8.16 , I am wondering how could I configure the node manager correctly so I could use it to control all of my managed servers , any ideas , I saw that in the 9 and above versions of weblogic , it is easy to deal with the node manager , my problem is that in the company it is hard to migrate the system to a new system for now ,

what is the best options ,[configuration] to make the node manager working ??